# MySQL row not being ordered in php page

Tags: php, mysql

Here you can see the code I use to display a table from a MySQL database in a PHP webpage:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","aaaaaa","bbbbb","my_mk7vrlist");
$x = 1;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 0_vrs_japan ORDER BY `vrs` DESC, `date` ASC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $x . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['playername'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><img src='http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/flags/" . $row['Country'] . ".gif' /></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contactable'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['vrs'] . "</td>";

  if($row['date'] != "-"){
   $formatted = date('jS F Y', strtotime($row['date']));
  } else {
   $formatted = "-";
  }

  if($row['pic'] != "-"){
   echo "<td><a href=\"" . $row['pic'] ."\" target=\"_blank\">" . $formatted . "</a></td>";
  } else {
   echo "<td>" . $formatted . "</td>";
  }

  echo "</tr>";
  $x = $x+1;
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Every player with 99'999 points (which are called 'vrs') is sorted by the `date`. I am having troubles with that player I have just added.

His date `2014/05/22` in the database isn't in the correct position (after Megaman). Do you have any idea?

Comment: What type of field are you using for the date in the DB?

Comment: what is the field type in which you are storing the date

Comment: That'll be the issue. If it was a date field it would be sortable.

Comment: is it stored in yyyy/mm/dd format?

Comment: If I'd change the field to 'date', will the '2014/05/22' format be still valid?

Comment: You'll probably need to write a migration script to ensure it can be converted without loss of data. Perhaps add the date column, then process the table and populate it, then you can drop the varchar column and proceed.

Comment: if you can't change field type you can use     order by STR_TO_DATE('2014/05/30', '%Y/%c/%d')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the date as a varchar so MySQL is having trouble sorting it in the way you need it to, as it's sorting lexicographically with the field being a varchar.

Convert them to proper date fields and natural date sorting will work as intended.

Comment: It's not really "having trouble" sorting it; it's just sorting the strings lexically, digit-by-digit, which isn't what you want.

Comment: @wyzard you're right, I should have phrased that differently. Will edit when I can.